# FTP Client Tool

Tags: ftp, notification

I am looking for a FTP Client only which can do following things:

- Send Notification email with list of Files/Folders, tree like structure after successful transfer.
- Send Notification email if any file/folder failed to upload.

I need help on this, please suggest if there is any tool which can do this.

Comment: You're going to have to give a lot more information than this.  What OS for a start?

Comment: If you're on OSX, [CyberDuck with Growl](https://trac.cyberduck.io/ticket/3807) is an option.

Answer (score 2):

From what I know, there's no tool that can notify you via email as a built-in feature. But there are some additional tools that can help you achieve this!

**Although, I just found this. [Wing FTP Server](http://www.wftpserver.com/) seems to exactly cover what you're looking for!** But I've not tested it and have no experience with it.

First you need a suitable FTP Client. If you don't know them already I'd recommend:

- [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/)
- [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/index.htm)

And then you need a small tool that notifies you about changes on the FTP (or what ever you'd like to get notified about). [You've got files](http://www.youvegotfiles.com/) seems like it could get this job done.